# overwriting cells from one pandas dataframe to another based on row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two data sets (blank and filled) as shown below, and I neet to copy information from `filled` into `blank`,

```
blank.head()
| Student name  | Student number    | Mark      | Grade     | Marked by     | Notes     |
|-------------- |----------------   |--------   |--------   |-----------    |--------   |
| John          |16                 | NaN       | NaN       | NaN           | NaN   |
| Mary          |19                 | NaN       | NaN       | NaN           | NaN   |
| Colm          |17                 | NaN       | NaN       | NaN           | NaN   |
| Ellen         |20                 | NaN       | NaN       | NaN           | NaN   |
| Fionna        |21                 | NaN       | NaN       | NaN           | NaN   |

filled.head()

| Student name  | Student number    | Mark  | Grade     | Marked by     | Notes                 |
|-------------- |----------------   |------ |-------    |-----------    |--------------------   |
| Tara          | 31                | 71    | B1        | JL            |        Good           |
| Leah          | 40                | 54    | C2        | CL            | Needs more dragons    |
| john          | 16                | 53    | C2        | MG            |        Good           |
| Aisling       | 200               | 60    | B3        | MOB           |    keep working       |
| Adam          | 88                | 74    | B1        | KOM           |  don't forget apa     |
```

blank is my main document with the order I want to maintain, filled contains the grades and other info filled in for each student but it is not in the same order as  df1.

I need to copy the columns  'Mark','Grade','Marked by' and 'Notes' from df2 to df1 keeping the index for df1 intact, and copying the right information for each student.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to use the student number as the index of both data frames (I'm guessing those are unique numbers) and then just copying like this:

```
blank.set_index('student number')
filled.set_index('student number')

list = ['Mark', 'Grade', 'Marked by', 'Notes'] 
blank[list] = filled[list]
```

...not sure if this would work for you though...

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Created the filled and blank dfs as exactly provided in the question since a key error was mentioned in the comment on my earlier code.

Input:

```
blank= pd.DataFrame({'Student name' : ['John','Mary','Colm','Ellen','Fionna'], "Student number": [16,19,17,20,21], 'Mark' : [np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],'Grade' : [np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN], 'Marked by' : [np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN], 'Notes' : [np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN]})
filled= pd.DataFrame({'Student name' : ['Tara','Leah','john','Aisling','Adam'], "Student number": [31,40,16,200,88], 'Mark' : [71,54,53,60,74],'Grade' : ['B1','C2','C2','B3','B1'], 'Marked by' : ['JL','CL','MG','MOB','KOM'], 'Notes' : ['Good','Needs more dragons','Good','keep working','dont forget apa']})
```

Blank:

```
  Student name  Student number  Mark Grade Marked by Notes
0         John              16  53.0    C2        MG  Good
1         Mary              19   NaN   NaN       NaN   NaN
2         Colm              17   NaN   NaN       NaN   NaN
3        Ellen              20   NaN   NaN       NaN   NaN
4       Fionna              21   NaN   NaN       NaN   NaN
```

Filled:

```
  Student name  Student number  Mark Grade Marked by               Notes
0         Tara              31    71    B1        JL                Good
1         Leah              40    54    C2        CL  Needs more dragons
2         john              16    53    C2        MG                Good
3      Aisling             200    60    B3       MOB        keep working
4         Adam              88    74    B1       KOM     dont forget apa
```

Assuming that 'student number' is common key for both data frames. Code below:

```
blank[['Mark','Grade','Marked by','Notes']] = blank.merge(filled,on='Student number')[['Mark_y', 'Grade_y','Marked by_y','Notes_y']]
```

Output:

```
  Student name  Student number  Mark Grade Marked by Notes
0         John              16  53.0    C2        MG  Good
1         Mary              19   NaN   NaN       NaN   NaN
2         Colm              17   NaN   NaN       NaN   NaN
3        Ellen              20   NaN   NaN       NaN   NaN
4       Fionna              21   NaN   NaN       NaN   NaN
```

Comment: For some reason I'm getting a key error, but I see where you're going, thanks I'll try to make it work.

Comment: Cool.. I only took few samples from your data frame and made my own. So please double check if my keys are spelt wrongly from yours..

Comment: Please see the double braces around keys also, that might be giving you the key error `[['Mark','Grade','Notes']]`

Comment: Would using iloc fix it?

Comment: Don't think so.. can you please post the df definition in the question.. it's very hard to replicate from df.head()

Comment: @KevOMalley743 - Please check if the code in my edited version resolves your issue. The dfs I used exactly matches your question